# How to connect asp.net to mysql on localhost and give iis permission to access mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I just started off on ASP.NET. Iam trying to configure a connection string on web.config so that it can connect to mysql database on localhost:3307 port. This is a sample code of what i have

```
<add name ="client" connectionString ="localhost:3307" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

And again any link on how to allow iis to access my server will be appreciated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554290/asp-net-mysql-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no

Answer (score -1, accepted):

On your web.config add this connection:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Then use ConfigurationManager to get this:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ConnectionString;

    using(SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

Then you can run Sql commands based on this connection, you don't need to configure IIS. Here is a simple [tutorial](http://www.tutsstore.com/asp-net-how-to-get-connection-string-from-web-config/) of how to do this!

Comment: Lemme check on That ASAP

Comment: Sorry, asi said i just started.. When you say i get configuration manager to get System.Dat.SqlClient; Using System.Configuration, Do you mean this configuration manager? because im having trouble doing that .. heresa screen shot of what i have https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0yUEFSpKSxmSlNqLVByR05tT2c/edit

Comment: try this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0yUEFSpKSxmSlNqLVByR05tT2c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: right click on your project/web solution and add reference..you dont need that screen

Comment: Question is about mysql, not SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

I had an older website that needed upgrading.  Took me a couple of days to change

DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver}

to

Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2 ANSI Driver}

I tried  dozens of things before I stumbled onto this one.  Add it to your list of things to try.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Suggestions should be placed as a comment rather than as an answer.