# ASP.NET Access denied for user (using password: NO) after deploy with msbuild/msdeploy

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, jenkins, msbuild

I'm setting up ci-deployment using jenkins for multiplice ASP.NET MVC 5 EF CF application with MySQL-Database on a Windows Server 2012 R2 node. The app gets compiled first using msbuild and then published on IIS with msdeploy. ConnectionStrings will be replaced using the `-setParamFile` parameter, which works.

The problem: After calling the app on the target server, I get the following MySQL error:

> `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException`: Access denied for user 'myUser'@'myIp' (using password: NO).

The [MySQL-Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-connecting.html) say that this means the clinent had tried to connect without password.

This is really confusing me because my ConnectionString certainly contains a password! In the Web.config from the folder of the IIS-App it looks like this:

```
<add name="MyContext" connectionString="Server=SERVERIP;Database=MYDBNAME;Uid=DATABASEUSER;Pwd=PWD;Convert Zero Datetime=True;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Which is valid, because the app is running fine on local debugging and a Windows Server 2012 R2 based testsystem, where I deployed the app using Web-Publishing function of Visual Studio.

I have the suspicion that my Web.config gets overwritten, but can't find out where and why. I took a look in the local [Machine.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325473/where-is-machine-config) file of the target-server, but [in contrast to another thread with nearly the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15554290/asp-net-mysql-access-denied-for-user-localhost-using-password-no) this isn't containing my ConnectionString (And I even can't imagine why this should gonna happen).

Comment: I have just replaced my Identity code with mysql and am encountering the same issue.